# Contact Builder Populations with Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

We are in the process of building a Journey that will involve splitting a customer base into two segments, one per business unit.

With regards to Populations, in terms of the user interface I've found that each Business Unit has its own set of Populations - but does anybody know if it is still shared across Business Units?

For example, can I set the main Data Extension as a Population at the Parent Business Unit, then fire those contacts into Journeys in the child business unit level? Or will I require a Population directly in the Business Unit where the Journey lives?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Contact Model and Populations within it are specific to each Business Unit. You can't share the Contact Model or populations across Business Units.